# ZMQ data transfer latency from one process to another?

Tags: zeromq

when using ZMQ transfer data, the transmitted port is fast and the data is huge, but the receive port processing is slow and the data is accumulated between the two processes. Does any one know how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: You want to transfer large data between two peers where the receiver is very slow? What language bindings are you using?

Comment: Please provide more detail about what you are doing and how you are trying to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending all the data at once, send in chunks instead. Somethings like this...

- Client requests file 'xyz' from server
- Server responds with file size only, ex: 10Mb
- Client sets chunk size accordingly, ex: 1024b
- Client sends read requests to server for chunks of data:

  client -> server: give me 0 to 1023 bytes for file 'xyz'
  server -> client: 1st chunk
  client -> server: give me 1024 to 2047 bytes for file 'xyz'
  server -> client: 2nd chunk
  ...and so on.
- For each response, client persists chunk to disk.

This approach allows the client to throttle the rate at which data is transmitted from the server. Also, in case of network failure, since each chunk is persisted, there's no need to read file from beginning; the client can start requesting more chunks from the point before the last response failed.

You mentioned nothing on language bindings, but this solution should be trivial to implement in just about any language.